# Injecting managed bean results in null

Tags: spring, jsf

I'm trying to pass a variable between two jsf pages. I have searched and tried some solutions from the internet but I'm stuck.

In my first_config.xml have a bean like this:

```
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>configBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            mypackage.ConfigBean
        </managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>domainName</property-name>
            <value>Config</value>
        </managed-property>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>configService</property-name>
            <value>#{configService}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
```

And in the second_config.xml, I injected that bean:

```
     <managed-bean>
            <managed-bean-name>accountSelfBean2</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>mypackage.AccountSelfBean</managed-bean-class>
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
            <managed-property>
              <property-name>domainName</property-name>
              <value>AccountSelf</value>
            </managed-property>  
            <managed-property>
              <property-name>configBean</property-name>
              <value>#{configBean}</value>
            </managed-property>
     </managed-bean>
```

And in AccountSelfBean.java class I already have get/set method:

```
private ConfigBean configBean;

    public ConfigBean getConfigBean() {
        return configBean;
    }

    public void setConfigBean(ConfigBean configBean) {
        this.configBean = configBean;
    }
```

However, when I try to debug this I see that my `configBean` is `null`.

Comment: Do you want inject a ManagedBean into another?

Comment: Off-Topic: Are you starting new with jsf and spring or taking over an old project? I ask this because you have a kind of 10 year old way of doing things

Comment: @KuKeltje You are right. I'm taking over an old project and also new to jsf and spring... But is there anything you can help me about this? I'm getting lost without basic understanding. Just search and work.

Comment: @MitsuGarcía Yes, I think so.

Comment: "Spring" actually adds a major ambiguity and red herring to the question as it's basically a whole different way of managing beans. Can you assure that existing beans are managed via JSF (the faces-config.xml way as you've shown in your question), and thus not via Spring (via its own xml file)? Because, when they are actually managed via Spring, a bunch of different preconditions has to be taken care of which isn't mentioned anywhere in your question in its current form.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, the bean are managed via jsf not spring bean.